# To add default filter to grid in Magento2?

Tags: collections, grid, magento2

I have created one custom module with title & status field attribute in admin grid.

Grid collections in **module_test_grid_block.xml**

```
        <arguments>
             <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">testGrid</argument>
             <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\test\Collection</argument>
             <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
             <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>                             
             <argument name="grid_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/grid"><param name="_current">1</param></argument>
         </arguments>
```

I just want to show the datas which are enabled.Have any option ***to add default filter in admin grid collections***?

Comment: Got an answer from magento stack! [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95371/to-add-default-filter-to-grid-in-magento2)